# How to get user input for array in MIPS

Tags: arrays, mips

Hello beginner with MIPS here, but I've been trying to get the user input in an array. When I go to print the array out though, it only prints 0s. The print function works when I pre fill the array though. Any help or advice would be appreciated.
Thanks!!

my code to get the user's input for the array is below:

The array size is supposed to be 6

```
    #counter
    addi $t0, $0, 0
    
    #saving the address of the array to $s0
input:
    beq $t0, 24, main2

#getting the input for the array
li $v0,4 
la $a0,msg1
syscall

li $v0,5
syscall
move $v0,$t1

sw $t1, nums3($t0)

    addi $t0, $t0, 4


j input
```

Comment: Your `move $v0, $t1` is backwards.  Right before that instruction, single stepping in the debugger, you will see the user input value in `$v0` from the syscall.  After that instruction, you'll no longer see the user input value in `$v0`.  You should have been able to see yourself this doing your own single step debugging.  If you don't know about debugging, now is a good time to learn.

Comment: Thank you so much!! You're a lifesaver!!